# Rails - error while showing field from class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, view, controller

i want to bring all the resources and then show the 'nombre' field that is from 'curso'. One curso has many resources.( I have all the has_many and belongs_to well configured.)

For that i do the following:
resources_controller:

```
 def index
     @resources = Resource.all 
end
```

index.html:

```
    <% @resources.each do |resource| %>
  <tr>
        <td><%= resource.title %></td>
        **<td><%= resource.curso.nombre %></td>**
        <td><%= resource.cantidad %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show   ', resource %></td>
    <% else %>

    <% end %>
```

but when i test it, it gives me the following error: "undefined method `nombre' for nil:NilClass"

do you know what can it be?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It means that this particular `resource` is not associated with any of your `curso`.

If you want to mandate that each `resource` should be associated with any of your `curso` while it's creation, you should have this in your `Resource` model:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curso

  # Validate the presence of curso in every resource.
  validates :curso, presence: true
end

class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base
  # When any curso is destroyed, all it's associated resources should be gone.
  has_many :resources, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Only in above case, you can ensure that resource always have a curso during it's creation.

Additionally, you can have DB level *not null* constraint on `curso_id` field of `resources` table.

Comment: After the changes, it still won't work for the existing data you already have. Try deleting all the resources, cursos and add data again, via rails  (if development env)

Comment: yes, its development env and I reset the DB. but it doesnt work

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you add how you are creating the data records in your question? We can't help with little of input.

Comment: i cant understand what you need. but i give you an example: if i want to use the same code to show a specific resource and i put this "      @ resources = Resource.where(:curso_id => params[:id])
      @ curso = Curso.find(params[:id])"  into index its work ok. the problem is when i try to show all the resources.

Comment: In rails console, what does this return you - `Resource.all.map(&:curso_id) - Curo.all.map(&:id)`

Comment: it returns me: irb(main):006:0> Resource.all.map(&:curso_id) - Curso.all.map(&:id)
  Resource Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources"
  Curso Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "cursos".* FROM "cursos"
=> []

Comment: And - `Resource.all.reject(&:curso)` ?

Comment: irb(main):007:0> Resource.all.reject(&:curso)
  Resource Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources"
  Curso Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "cursos".* FROM "cursos" WHERE "cursos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> []

Comment: Both of these justify that there is no such resource without curso. I'm not sure why you are still getting that exception in your rails' view code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some `resources` don`t have a`curso`.

Just check if the `curso` exists before calling `nombre` on it:

```
<%= resource.curso.nombre if resource.curso %>
```

or

```
<%= resource.curso && resource.curso.nombre %>
```

or

```
<%= resource.curso.try(:nombre) %>
```